# Subchapters in RAML?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, raml

In Github-flavored RAML, is there a way to create subchapters in the documentation tag?

For example, given this:

```
documentation:
  - title: "Overview"
    content: !include documentation/overview.md

  - title: "Getting Started"
    content: !include documentation/getting-started.md
```

can you add two chapters under Getting Started, like:

```
documentation:
  - title: "Overview"
    content: !include documentation/overview.md

  - title: "Getting Started"
    content: !include documentation/getting-started.md
       - title: "Intro 1"
         content: !include documentation/Intro_1.md
       - title: "Intro 2"
         content: !include documentation/Intro_2.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No content has to be a string. So no sub chapters are allowed. The best you can get is multiple top level chapters and then headings within your markdown content.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Can't add subchapters? The problem is I can't have anchor links (links within the same page) in RAML either. For the life of me I can't see why people like RAML.